# Google Cloud Monitoring (Stackdriver) not showing deployment events in Event Log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

For some reason I do not see any deployment events in Event log for one of my Google App Engine project (project2). I have another project that logs events fine (project1). I can not recall whether or not I did some additional changes to the project1. I am missing something, or is this an issue on the Google/Stackdriver side?

[image: event log]

EDIT: I created the project2 from the Google Developer console (web UI). After that I deployed using the same deployment script as I use for project1:

```
appcfg.py -A project-name update app.yaml ember.yaml .
appcfg.py -A project-name update_dispatch .
```

Do you need to enable deployment events somehow separately from Google Console or Stackdrive console?

Comment: There isn't enough info for anyone to tell. Please let us know what you did when you set up project2.

Comment: I basically created the project2 from Google Developer console and deployed with the same deployment script I used to deploy project1. I added EDIT to my main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has taken some time but we have acknowledged the issue and added this to our public issue tracker here:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12638